# Debugging "field integrity exception" error when deploying change set from sandbox to production

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to deploy a change set that contains a Flow Version. I've also tried deploying it as a whole new flow to no avail.

[image: field integrity exception]

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm also facing the same issue on deploying a flow, have raised a case with Salesforce for the same.

Comment: Yes. I have multiple Apex Webservices implemented in the Flow and some changes were made to the Apex Class of one of them but never deployed to Production. I had to check every element of the Flow and compare between Sandbox and Production until I noticed this since SF doesn't give any details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I ran test classes of the plugins / invocable apex in the target org which are referred from the flow but the same field integrity exception comes while deploying the flow.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped just to change the API version of a few flows to the current one.